# Capture group from regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following string `/path/to/my-jar-1.0.jar` for which I am trying to write a bash regex to pull out `my-jar`.

Now I believe the following regex would work: `([^\/]*?)-\d` but I don't know how to get bash to run it.

The following: `echo '/path/to/my-jar-1.0.jar' | grep -Po '([^\/]*?)-\d'` captures `my-jar-1`

Answer (score 5):

In BASH you can do:

```
s='/path/to/my-jar-1.0.jar'

[[ $s =~ .*/([^/[:digit:]]+)-[[:digit:]] ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

my-jar
```

Here `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` will print captured group #1 which is expression inside first `(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as well with shell prefix and suffix removal:

```
$ path=/path/to/my-jar-1.0.jar
# Remove the longest prefix ending with a slash
$ base="${path##*/}"
# Remove the longest suffix starting with a dash followed by a digit
$ base="${base%%-[0-9]*}"
$ echo "$base"
my-jar
```

Although it's a little annoying to have to do the transform in two steps, it has the advantage of only using Posix features so it will work with any compliant shell.

Note: The order is important, because the basename cannot contain a slash, but a path component could contain a dash. So you need to remove the path components first.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -o` doesn't recognize "capture groups" I think, just the entire match. That said, with Perl regexps (`-P`) you have the "lookahead" option to exclude the `-\d` from the match:

```
echo '/path/to/my-jar-1.0.jar' | grep -Po '[^/]*(?=-\d)'
```

Some reference material on lookahead/lookbehind:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444